# Will a shorter version of our domain show up in Google?

Tags: google, 301-redirect, multiple-domains

Our domain is www.blablablablaXXblablablba.com
We do not want to change this, but instead we want to "add" a redirection domain (301 redirect): www.XX.eu (which will make it easier for people to remember our domain name on events etc)

However if we buy www.XX.eu, we know that people won't always type it in the address bar, but sometimes google the entire domain name. Will google show either the long domain name, the shorter 301 domain name (which on click redirects to long domain name) or nothing of those two (which would be the worst option)

Comment: Buy domain xx.eu and use long name in your Homepage title tag.

Comment: Your redirects are 302 and not 301. You can see this by using a [CURL](https://onlinecurl.com/) on an old URL.

Comment: @SimonHayter I think your comment is intended for a different question?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply buy a new/short domain and 301 redirect it to your actual domain then it will never appear in the Google search results.

If you want to use the short domain for marketing purposes (easier to remember, easier to fit on your business card, etc.) then by all means use it, but it will do nothing to help your search engine ranking.

> Will google show either the long domain name, the shorter 301 domain name (which on click redirects to long domain name) or nothing of those two (which would be the worst option)

Since the "long domain name" is the one you are actually using on your site, the one you are linking to, etc. then this will be the domain that appears in the SERPs.